# Tesseract-OCR 4 (C++ API) is about 5 times slower than python (pytesseract)

Tags: python, c++, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Recently I've tried to use `Tesseract-OCR API` (C++, version 4) and I discovered that it's much slower than OCRing with python using `pytesseract`. The point is that as far as I know `pytesseract` accessing the `Tesseract-OCR CLI` that leads to slow performance. As far as I've read until now, to optimize OCR performance (in my case compared to `pytesseract`) is to directly use the `Tesseract OCR API` (C++).

With that knowledge, I configured everything in my `Visual Studio` & run the following C++ from [Tesseract-OCR Documentation on Github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/APIExample.md):

```
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    if (api->Init("C:/Users/benja/source/repos/OCR/tessdata", "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("C:/Users/benja/Desktop/page.jpg");
    api->SetImage(image);
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);
    
    api->End();
    delete api;
    delete[] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);
    
    return 0;
}
```

With C++ the process ran for **22.0851577 seconds** while with `pytesseract` code it ran just **4.4216025 seconds**

Python `pytesseract` code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread(r"C:/Users/benja/Desktop/page.jpg")

outText = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=r'-l eng')

print(outText)
```

Now I'm wondering (in order to understand this topic better), how it's even possible that `C++` is slower than `Python` when `C++` access the `Tesseract OCR API` **directly** (according to the documentation) while 'pytesseract' access the `Tesseract OCR CLI`?

Edit:
I've tried both versions (Python & C++) on the same image and also get the same output text.

Comment: Are the OCR results exactly the same for both the Python and C++ version for a range of images? Tesseract has a lot of modes with different speed/accuracy tradeoffs, so even a tiny difference may indicate that the model differs. Also is the relative timing difference the same if you only time the Tesseract call versus all the IO?

Comment: @Meowf I've tried the both versions on the same image & received the same result.

Comment: I tried building the cpp-version (I had to change the first path to `/usr/share/tessdata/`) against library version `tesseract-4.1.1`, and comparing it to `pytesseract-0.3.8`, and I get slightly differing OCR-output between the two (newlines in particular). Additionally, the python one is around a second slower for me. Perhaps the package/library versions might matter here? They each took around 1-2 seconds but that almost certainly comes down to the resolution of the image (mine was small).

Comment: Not sure if your image is "easy" but do they still give the same result if you try an image with a lot of line breaks and spaced out text like screenshots of webpages (quick example I found: https://business.twitter.com/content/dam/business-twitter/en/resources/blog/q3-2021/how-to-advanced-search-on-twitter-one.jpg.twimg.1920.jpg )? I should add, in this case for this image the cpp-version is slower for me than the python one (and their outputs differ greatly).

Comment: Random guess: your C++ program (or the tesseract library) was compiled in Debug mode instead of optimized Release mode.

Comment: Edit your question with how you built tesseract.

Comment: @Botje, Nevermind, your guess was right, in optimized release mode, it took just 4.7923139 seconds.